# Excel VBA programming executing a VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am in charge of keeping a record of the fees and payments in my club and so I decided to make an Excel page for it. I am new to Excel VBA programming, so I need some advice.

My idea is: if the person is present but didn't pay, I just mark an `x`, if he is present and just payed, I would like to be able to mark an `N` and make it so that a msgbox pops up asking the value of the payment and directly puts that value in a precise cell on another page.

```
Sub Pay()
    Dim Pay As String
    Pay = InputBox("Enter A New Payment", "Payment", "Enter amount here")
    Range("'versement adherent'!C15").Value = Pay
End Sub
```

So that was my idea for the msgbox but it is too narrow, it only starts if asked to (doesn't start automatically when a cell with the value `N` is written) and the cell in which it writes the value is always the same.

```
Private Sub FindN(StrSearchQuery As String)
    Set SearchRange = Range("versement adherent!F2:Y21")
    FindN = StrSearchQuery

    Function FindAll(SearchRange As Range, LookFor As String)
        Dim FoundCell As Range

        For Each area In SearchRange.Areas
            With area
                If .cell(.cell.Count).Row > MaxRow Then
                    MaxRow = .cell(.cell.Count).Column
                End If
            End With

        Next area
        Set lastcell = SearchRange.Worksheet.Cells(MaxRow, MaxCol)
        Do Until True
            Set FoundCell = SearchRange.Find(N)
            If FoundCell = False Then
        Exit Do

        If FoundCell = True Then
            For Each FoundCell In Worksheet("versement adherent").Range(FoundCell)
                Range("versement adherent !Foundcell").Value = Pay
                Range(FoundCell).Value = X
            Exit Do

        End If
    End Function

    Set FoundCell = FindAll

    If FoundCell = True Then
        For Each FoundCell In Worksheet("versement adherent").Range(FoundCell)
        Range("versement adherent !Foundcell").Value = Pay
    End If
```

I've tried adding some code to make the part where it finds a cell with the value N but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Worksheet_Change` event.

I will admit, with your example code, it was hard to fully understand what you were trying to do, but I based my code on your explanation.

My code below makes the assumption that a given person's name is in column A and the cell to mark X or N is in column B (so right next to the person's name).

It also makes the assumption that you just want to enter the payment amount for each person **once** in the `versement adherent` sheet. It assumes the person's name is listed in that sheet in column Y. It searches column Y for that name and places in the payment amount in column Z right next to the person's name.

This obviously will need to be tweaked for your exact requirements, but should be easy to do so given the comments I have made. However, if my assumptions are way-off base, let me know in the comments and I can probably adjust for you :)

Place the code below inside the Worksheet Module where you mark X or N and adjust for your specific ranges, sheet names etc. The code will fire each time you mark an `N` for a person.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)

If Target.Column = 2 And UCase(Target.Value2) = "N" ' assumes you enter x or N in column B

   Dim Pay As String
   Pay = InputBox("Enter A New Payment", "Payment", "Enter amount here")

   'now find the name in versement adherent sheet
   With Worksheets("versement adherent")

       'first find last row to search
       Dim lRow as Long
       lRow = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row

       'search column Y for the name
       Dim rPayCell as Range
       Set rPayCell = .Range("Y2:Y" & lRow).Find(Target.Offset(,-1).Value2

       If Not rPayCell is Nothing Then 
          rPayCell.Offset(,1).Value = Pay 'if name is found place payment in column Z
       Else 'otherwise alert
          Msgbox "Name Not Found in Versement Adherent Sheet"
       End If

   End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your time, i've looked at the code but there are some things i still don't really understand, shouldn't it be  `worksheet_change(byval target as range)` followed by `target.worksheet("versement adherent")` instead of `worksheet_change( target as range) with worksheet("versement adherent")` ? @ScottHoltzmann

Comment: I made two typos. Sorry. I fixed them in the edited code. `ByVal` should have been in the `Worksheet_Change` argument, as you pointed out. However `With Worksheet("verse ...` should have been `With Worksheets("verse ...`.  Saying `Target.Worksheet` does not make sense in VBA syntax, since `Target` is a range. *(You can refer to the Target Worksheet by using `Target.Parent` however)*

Comment: hello again, I worked a little more on the code but encountered a few new issues. Here's the thing, So here's my question, First of all, how do i extend this code from `If Target.column = 6 And UCase ...` to targeting all columns from 6 to 25? Second question, The code works great but not for every row. for example if i write the N in the cell on column 6 and row 8 it might write the payment in the cell on column 6 but row 20. @ScottHoltzman

Comment: I should probably tell you this to make it easier to understand, on the `versement adherent` worksheet I have  in column `A` I have the names of the people, and in columns `C to U` I have the payments. On the `presence` page in column `A` I have the names and in column `F to Y` I write a `X` or an `N`.
Also on the `versement adherent` page, the payments should be put in a cell according to the cell in which the N was written
(column 3 in both sheets for example)
I think the part where it finds the name might not be working great because it should normally write the payment in front of the name